# Neo4j: Comparing relation attribute which is array type

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to list out the number of matches Liverpool have lost.

my code:

```
match(a:Club{name:'Liverpool FC'})-[r:played_with]->(b:Club)
WHERE r.score[0]<r.score[1] return count(r) as result
UNION
match(a:Club)-[r:played_with]->(b:Club{name:'Liverpool FC'})
WHERE r.score[0]>r.score[1] return count(r) as result
```

I expect one result but it shows two.

[image: Data model]

Comment: Two comments ... 1) the above syntax can not work, the r.score[0]1 in the first query is not correct ... 2) unless both queries return exactly the same count the UNION will obviously return two results ... what is it you want to do ?

Answer (score 2):

[UPDATED]

If you want to see how many times Liverpool FC lost, you can just use a non-directional relationship pattern:

```
MATCH (a:Club{name:'Liverpool FC'})-[r:played_with]-(:Club)
WHERE CASE WHEN a = STARTNODE(r)
  THEN r.score[0]<r.score[1]
  ELSE r.score[1]<r.score[0] END
RETURN COUNT(r) as result;
```

Comment: As pointed by @InverseFalcon in an answer that I have deleted, in this case the relationship direction matters, since the first element in the array refers to the score of the club at the starting node of the relationship, and the second element refers to the score of the club at the end node of the relationship

Comment: Very nice, I like this approach

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need UNION to make this work. Try this instead:

```
MATCH (a:Club{name:'Liverpool FC'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:played_with]->(:Club)
WHERE r.score[0]<r.score[1] 
WITH a, count(r) as result1
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)<-[r:played_with]-()
WHERE r.score[0]>r.score[1] 
WITH a, result1, count(r) as result2
RETURN result1 + result2
```

Comment: Thank You ....
"WITH a, result1, count(r) as result2"  and  "WITH a, result1, count(r) as result2"......didn't understand these lines could you please explain

Comment: Sure, WITH is used to both redefine which variables are in scope, and to execute functions on current variables. `WITH a, count(r) as result1` means, for each `a` node, we're getting the count of `r`, which is the number of relationships of that type and direction where the associated WHERE clause applies. The other WITH clause does the same thing, but also keeps the `result1` variable in scope, since we'll need it for the addition in the RETURN